# Grails one to one relation

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I tried to define one to one relation in 2 different way:
Grails 2.0.3

Case 1:

```
class Car {
    String model  
    Engine eng  
    static constraints = {
        eng unique: true
    }
}

class Engine {
    Double capacity
    static belongsTo = [car : Car]
}
```

Case 2:

```
class Car {
    String model
    static hasOne = [eng : Engine]
    static constraints = {
        eng unique: true
    }
}


class Engine {
    Double capacity
    static belongsTo = [car : Car]
}
```

looks similar, and both provide one to one bidirectional mapping. Unfortunately DB has different structure in both cases.

Case 1:
[image]

Case 2:
[image]

Why once Car and once Engine keeps link to second table.

Where is my problem? When I am looking at the code, from DDD perspective, both cases suggest that Car class is more important and Car aggregates Engine. Unfortunately when I look from DB side on case 2 I would rather said that it is opposite - Engine aggregate Car. Of course I can use first approach, but most of publication I saw about grails, present second way for defining relation. Maybe I misunderstood something and I use hasOne in wrong way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [documentation on `hasOne`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html) states that using this creates a bi-directional one-to-one relationship where the foreign key is on the child.

The [`belongsTo`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html) means that actions performed on the parent (eg save and update) will be cascaded by hibernate to the child.

So if you want the foreign key to be on `Engine` use `static hasOne = [engine:Engine]` on `Car`.

If you want the foreign key to be on `Car` then use `Engine engine` on `Car` .

In both cases use `belongsTo = [car: Car]` on `Engine`

Comment: Great explanation! `belongsTo` doesn´t create the the relationship with foreign key, but other cases do. Just you need to study where you think the foreign keys should be.

Comment: `belongsTo` is not needed in both cases. in `hasOne` or `hasMany` it´s needed. But if you want to create a "Use relationship", `belongsTo` is not needed because you dont want to delete the other object.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to make this aproach.

```
   class Car {
       String model
       Engine engine
       static constraints = {
           eng unique: true
       }
   }


   class Engine {
       Double capacity
       Car car
   }
```

I think that will make it. You can read it here:

> By default the address association would map to a foreign key column
>   called address_id.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html

on the **Many-to-One/One-to-One Mappings**

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am not sure but, Is this is right way to map.... because Engine engine resembles Many-to-one and then setting the constraint to unique...Does it making any point? You can go with hasOne their...